# URL with hostname doesn't work but it works with IP Address

Tags: dns, hostname

I have a very basic question here. This thing is puzzling me a little bit.

I have one Ubuntu machine which is running 12.04 and I am connecting to that machine from putty in my desktop (which is running windows).

I started Netflix Exhibitor like this in that Ubuntu machine -

```
cronusapp@phx5qa01c:/zook$ java -jar ./exhibitor-1.5.1/lib/exhibitor-1.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -c file
v1.5.1
INFO  com.netflix.exhibitor.core.activity.ActivityLog  Exhibitor started [main]
INFO  org.mortbay.log  Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog [main]
INFO  org.mortbay.log  jetty-1.5.1 [main]
Dec 18, 2013 7:10:35 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9.1 09/14/2011 02:36 PM'
INFO  org.mortbay.log  Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 [main]
```

And then I went to chrome browser in my desktop and I opened the url like this with the machine hostname -

```
http://phx5qa01c.stratus.phx.qa.host.com:8080/exhibitor/v1/ui/index.html
```

And this url is showing me blank white page on the screen. But if I replace the hostname with IP Address of that machine, then it starts working and I can see the actual content on my browser.

```
http://10.108.24.132:8080/exhibitor/v1/ui/index.html
```

Now I am not sure why this is happening. Is there any file which I am supposed to modify in my Ubuntu box to recognize the hostname instead of ip address.

I believe this is pretty basic question which I am not aware of? Any idea what I am supposed to do to fix this?

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I have done to figure out the IP Address, I am taking IP Address for etho -

```
root@phx5qa01c:/home/david# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:ad:5b:a9
          inet addr:10.108.24.132  Bcast:10.108.27.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:351211 errors:0 dropped:590 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:291409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:426570999 (426.5 MB)  TX bytes:39383233 (39.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:15839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1455090 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1455090 (1.4 MB)
```

And below is for the hostname -

```
root@phx5qa01c:/home/david# hostname -f
phx5qa01c.stratus.phx.qa.host.com
```

**UPDATE2:-**

This is what I got after nslookup from my desktop -

```
david@desktop /cygdrive/c/ApacheExhibitor/Exhibitor-1.5.1/target
$ nslookup phx5qa01c.stratus.phx.qa.host.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  sjd-entdc-001.corp.host.com
Address:  10.244.128.25

Name:    phx5qa01c.stratus.phx.qa.host.com
Address:  10.108.24.132
```

Comment: Are you sure that `phx5qa01c.stratus.phx.qa.host.com` resolves to `10.108.24.132`?

Comment: How to find out that hostname actually resolves to that IP Address? I have updated the question with a small update..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your hostname doesn't resolve to the IP address ( you can check it by pinging your hostname) add an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file like below

`10.108.24.132 phx5qa01c.stratus.phx.qa.host.com`

**Update**
For windows machines hosts file is in `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: see my updated question.. It is getting resolved to that IP address after doing nslookup from my desktop..

Comment: Does that hostname resolves from the Windows machine

Answer (score 1):

Soem webservers like apache can be configured to deliver different content for different hostnames (and still have the same IP). That could be the case here as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting