# Browse by hostname from internet browser

Tags: centos, hostname, hosts

I can browse my server site using

```
 ip:8080
```

which is inside my home network.But I am not able to browse using

```
 hostname:8080
```

I do not have dns server. I have edited /etc/hosts file to include hostname and ip. I can ping using hostname.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.16.2.12 apple.myserver.com
10.16.2.22 ball.myserver.com
10.16.2.20 cat.myserver.com
10.16.2.19 dog.myserver.com
10.16.2.18 elep.myserver.com
```

Similar Issue [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105828/url-with-hostname-doesnt-work-but-it-works-with-ip-address).

Comment: Does it also not work if you explicitly say `http://hostname:8080`? Browsers have become worse in recognizing what is not a "omnibox" style search query.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz It does not work. But when I use IP it works. I use mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have DNS (so it is not registered and not resolving globally) then all you need is to add the same host entry in your PC/laptop in order to access to it via hostname.

Comment: I already havve it in /etc/hosts

Comment: apparently you have the wrong setup. pls post the output of "cat /etc/hosts && hostname -f " and also ping the hostname from the host itself.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: if pinging the hostname replies then it should work. you didn/t posted the output for hostname -f. also it is all on single machine right? I mean you have everything on one machine? because it sounds like that, otherwise pls be more specific if you are using 2 separate machines.

Comment: I have many machines. virtual machines! hostname -f results one of hostname.

Comment: can you be more specific pls, do you have virtual or physical machines? and if so, pls edit your post and add the proper information i.e. my pc is called X with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, my VM is called Y with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and I can't access via browser from X to Y using hostname:8080. If this is your case pls provide this information, we don't need real info about your setup but just what is what. We dont have crystal balls here to understand what you have and therefore it is difficult to help. thx

Comment: pls also confirm if the above hosts entry is from server side or PC side.

Comment: I don't think it would matter much being VM or physical server. I can ping form one server to another and telnet into the port .I would want to browse using browser which doesn't work.